# Questions that don't require explaining what was done to try to solve it

Tags: discussion, questions, ask-question-wizard-2018

When developing it's normal to find an obstacle. To go through it, we generally start with a question, "How can I solve this?" (being solved defined as X)

Most of the time we manage to go through it, answer the question and go on with the development. Problem is, that answer we found might not be as straightforward for other persons and / or for us in the future.

So, since yesterday I'm experimenting with looking at StackOverflow as repository of QAs from even looking like "minor" problems.

When asking a question in Stack, we are able to select a guide mode and, when writing the description, we can read and see in the image:

> Provide background including what you've already tried

[image: StackOverflow]

Problem here is, sometimes by writing what we did, then there's no question at all in the first place.

It exists such a thing as *Questions that don't require explaining what was done to try to solve it* or am i the only one seeing this?

This is very similar to

- [Should we ask questions to "rubber duck" the solution?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/60552/364217)

except we don't get the answer while typing but we managed to solve without Stack and we are told, not specifically, to not do that (during the process of asking questions). The involvement of Stack would be to keep track of it (repository, just like i mentioned previously).

May I keep on doing it (asking and answering to keep track)?

Comment: Pretty much all questions require this. It's just necessary background information. In the few cases where "[show] what you've already tried" doesn't apply, the near-equivalent "show your research effort" does. So no, we don't want to remove this text from the Ask Question wizard. Especially since the wizard is only shown to users who are relatively new to asking questions. Experienced Stack Overflow users can bypass the wizard, and ask questions based on what they know from their experience is acceptable here.

Comment: Even if the research effort enables one to solve the question? This could mean StackOverflow might not be the repository some are looking for.

Comment: Yes. Not all questions belong on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Got it, thank you @Cody Gray. Transform these types of question into "show your research effort" it is.

Comment: @TiagoMartinsPeres "_Even if the research effort enables one to solve the question?_", then thats great! There is an option to "self answer" - but all question should still be posed as a problem to solve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the moderator Cody Gray, not all questions belong here, which is understandable. For Stack Overflow, in general one needs to at least "show research effort" (being that explaining which terms you've used to searched for, linls visited, relevant info that really didn't match what were looking for) except:

- Canonical questions
- FAQ questions

Still, questions of this type require to say it.

So, if you do get across a question that  you feel it doesn't require explaination, you're better of transforming it into an "at least show research effort", canonical or FAQ.

Comment: Intentional FAQ questions don't require this, as long as you specify that in your question and post an answer with the question.

Comment: Hm... that's not what the moderator @Cody Gray said to me.

Comment: [*"the wizard is only shown to users who are relatively new to asking questions. Experienced Stack Overflow users can bypass the wizard, and ask questions based on what they know from their experience is acceptable here."*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/390347/questions-that-dont-require-explaining-what-was-done-to-try-to-solve-it#comment734250_390347) Canonical FAQs are permitted, although it is generally expected that there will be some motivation provided in the question itself, even for a FAQ.